# dell 3446 ubuntu 18.04 LTS integted web cam not working,any driver for that?

Tags: webcam

Driver for the integrated webcam
I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop. Previously it was Windows. Earlier my laptop's webcam was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search "Additional Drivers" on
[Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txar9.png)

Comment: not working I don't see any additional driver